# Android Fragments default select first item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In Android Studio I have selected a new project based on master / detail flow. The project works as it should be. Now I want to extend it. As of now the content of the items in the detail fragment are only shown when I click an item on the list. I want that the top item is selected automaticaly when the app starts. I thought I put in ItemListFragment just a method call

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(0).id);
}
```

that a click is simulated in the lifecycle once all objects are initialized. That fails. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you try it in onResume()? I always put it in onResume()

**UPDATE #1**

You can try my way to implement the selection. Normally i don't use the select of list view.

1.In your data model, create a boolean field called "selection".

2.When you apply data to your adapter, set the first data "selection" to true.

3.In your adapter getView callback, try to handles your data "selection" such as:

```
if (!dummyData.selection){
    do something when not select....
}else{
    do something when selected...
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
put this code in ItemListFragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(0).id);
}
```

Comment: have you try the code snipet of @Ibtehaz Shawon in onResume? If i don't guess wrong, you're trying to call onItemSelected callback of your listview manually?

Comment: I use the "official" Android sample code, when you create this master / detail project. There is no custom adapter.

Comment: Wait a minute. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first element by the following code

```
yourListView.setSelection(0);
yourListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers mate! :)

Comment: in onStart getSelectedView is null. so that doesn't work.

Comment: in what lifecycle method is the listview full? onStart is already pretty late in the lifecycle. When shall I call it?

Comment: You could do this as soon as you set the adapter

Comment: in the ItemListFragment the adapter is set in onCreate. I try to execute the code above after that call. But that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences. You can save first item of listview as preference when create listview, then you can use it later.